Override a function inside a Child Class WorddPress Plugin
So I've been trying to override a method inside a child class, originally I modified the original files but that would get deleted with every plugin update, therefore I wanted to create a custom plugin to constantly override that method to check for a few things before it fires, here's the class :
<?php
/**
 * Submit Form
 *
 * @package    wp-freeio
 * @author     Habq 
 * @license    GNU General Public License, version 3
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

class WP_Freeio_Service_Submit_Form extends WP_Freeio_Service_Abstract_Form {
    public $form_name = 'wp_freeio_service_submit_form';
    

    private static $_instance = null;

    public static function get_instance() {
        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'process' ) );

        $this->get_steps();

        if ( !empty( $_REQUEST['submit_step'] ) ) {
            $step = is_numeric( $_REQUEST['submit_step'] ) ? max( absint( $_REQUEST['submit_step'] ), 0 ) : array_search( intval( $_REQUEST['submit_step'] ), array_keys( $this->steps ), true );
            $this->step = $step;
        }

        $this->service_id = ! empty( $_REQUEST['service_id'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['service_id'] ) : 0;

        if ( ! WP_Freeio_User::is_freelancer_can_edit_service( $this->service_id ) ) {
            $this->service_id = 0;
        }
        do_action('wp_freeio_submit_service_construct', $this);
        add_filter( 'cmb2_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'fields_front' ) );
        
    }

    public function get_steps() {
        $this->steps = apply_filters( 'wp_freeio_submit_service_steps', array(
            'submit'  => array(
                'view'     => array( $this, 'form_output' ),
                'handler'  => array( $this, 'submit_process' ),
                'priority' => 10,
            ),
            'preview' => array(
                'view'     => array( $this, 'preview_output' ),
                'handler'  => array( $this, 'preview_process' ),
                'priority' => 20,
            ),
            'done'    => array(
                'before_view' => array( $this, 'done_handler' ),
                'view'     => array( $this, 'done_output' ),
                'priority' => 30,
            )
        ));

        uasort( $this->steps, array( 'WP_Freeio_Mixes', 'sort_array_by_priority' ) );

        return $this->steps;
    }

    public function submit_process() {
        
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['submit-cmb-service'] ) || empty( $_POST[WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX.'post_type'] ) || 'service' !== $_POST[WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX.'post_type'] ) {
            return;
        }
        
        $cmb = cmb2_get_metabox( WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX . 'front' );
        if ( ! isset( $_POST[ $cmb->nonce() ] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $cmb->nonce() ], $cmb->nonce() ) ) {
            return;
        }
        // Setup and sanitize data
        if ( isset( $_POST[ WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX . 'title' ] ) ) {
            $post_id = $this->service_id;

            $post_status = 'preview';
            if ( ! empty( $post_id ) ) {
                $old_post = get_post( $post_id );
                $post_date = $old_post->post_date;
                $old_post_status = get_post_status( $post_id );
                if ( $old_post_status === 'draft' || $old_post_status === 'expired' ) {
                    $post_status = 'preview';
                } else {
                    $post_status = $old_post_status;
                }
            } else {
                $post_date = '';
            }
            
            $freelancer_user_id = WP_Freeio_User::get_user_id();
            $data = array(
                'post_title'     => sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX . 'title' ] ),
                'post_author'    => $freelancer_user_id,
                'post_status'    => $post_status,
                'post_type'      => 'service',
                'post_date'      => $post_date,
                'post_content'   => wp_kses_post( $_POST[ WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX . 'description' ] ),
            );

            $new_post = true;
            if ( !empty( $post_id ) ) {
                $data['ID'] = $post_id;
                $new_post = false;
            } else {
                if ( apply_filters('wp-freeio-update-slug-submit-service', true) ) {
                    $service_slug = array();

                    // Prepend with freelancer.
                    $freelancer_slug = wp_freeio_get_option('submission_service_slug_freelancer', 'on');
                    if ( $freelancer_slug == 'on' ) {
                        $freelancer_slug = true;
                    } else {
                        $freelancer_slug = false;
                    }
                    $freelancer_id = WP_Freeio_User::get_freelancer_by_user_id($freelancer_user_id);
                    $freelancer_name = get_the_title($freelancer_id);
                    if ( apply_filters( 'wp-freeio-submit-service-form-prefix-post-name-with-company', $freelancer_slug ) && !empty( $freelancer_name ) ) {
                        $service_slug[] = $freelancer_name;
                    }

                    // Prepend category.
                    $category_slug = wp_freeio_get_option('submission_service_slug_category', 'on');
                    if ( $category_slug == 'on' ) {
                        $category_slug = true;
                    } else {
                        $category_slug = false;
                    }
                    if ( apply_filters( 'wp-freeio-submit-service-form-prefix-post-name-with-category', $category_slug ) && !empty($_POST[WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX.'category']) ) {
                        $slugs = $_POST[WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX.'category'];
                        if ( is_array($slugs) ) {
                            foreach ($slugs as $slug) {
                                if ( is_numeric($slug) ) {
                                    $term = get_term($slug, 'service_category');
                                    if ( $term && $term->slug ) {
                                        $service_slug[] = $term->slug;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $service_slug[] = $slug;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if ( is_numeric($slugs) ) {
                                $term = get_term($slugs, 'service_category');
                                if ( $term && $term->slug ) {
                                    $service_slug[] = $term->slug;
                                }
                            } else {
                                $service_slug[] = $slugs;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $service_slug[] = $data['post_title'];
                    $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( implode( '-', $service_slug ) );
                }
            }

            do_action( 'wp-freeio-process-submission-before-save', $post_id, $this );

            $data = apply_filters('wp-freeio-process-submission-data', $data, $post_id);
            
            $this->errors = $this->submission_validate($data);
            if ( sizeof($this->errors) ) {
                return;
            }

            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $data, true );

            if ( ! empty( $post_id ) ) {
                $_POST['object_id'] = $post_id; // object_id in POST contains page ID instead of service ID

                $freelancer_id = WP_Freeio_User::get_freelancer_by_user_id($freelancer_user_id);
                $author_id = update_post_meta($post_id, WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX . 'freelancer_posted_by', $freelancer_id);

                $cmb->save_fields( $post_id, 'post', $_POST );

                // Create featured image
                $featured_image = get_post_meta( $post_id, WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX . 'featured_image', true );
                if ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'current_' . WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX . 'featured_image' ] ) ) {
                    $img_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX . 'featured_image_img', true );
                    if ( !empty($featured_image) ) {
                        if ( is_array($featured_image) ) {
                            $img_id = $featured_image[0];
                        } elseif ( is_integer($featured_image) ) {
                            $img_id = $featured_image;
                        } else {
                            $img_id = WP_Freeio_Image::get_attachment_id_from_url($featured_image);
                        }
                        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $img_id );
                    } else {
                        update_post_meta( $post_id, WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX . 'featured_image', null );
                        delete_post_thumbnail( $post_id );
                    }
                } else {
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX . 'featured_image', null );
                    delete_post_thumbnail( $post_id );
                }

                do_action( 'wp-freeio-process-submission-after-save', $post_id );

                if ( $new_post ) {
                    setcookie( 'service_add_new_update', 'new' );
                } else {
                    setcookie( 'service_add_new_update', 'update' );
                }
                $this->service_id = $post_id;
                $this->step ++;

            } else {
                if( $new_post ) {
                    $this->errors[] = __( 'Can not create service', 'wp-freeio' );
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = __( 'Can not update service', 'wp-freeio' );
                }
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    public function submission_validate( $data ) {
        $error = array();
        if ( empty($data['post_author']) ) {
            $error[] = __( 'Please login to submit service', 'wp-freeio' );
        }
        if ( empty($data['post_title']) ) {
            $error[] = __( 'Title is required.', 'wp-freeio' );
        }
        if ( empty($data['post_content']) ) {
            $error[] = __( 'Description is required.', 'wp-freeio' );
        }
        $error = apply_filters('wp-freeio-submission-validate', $error);
        return $error;
    }

    public function preview_output() {
        global $post;

        if ( $this->service_id ) {
            $post              = get_post( $this->service_id ); // WPCS: override ok.
            $post->post_status = 'preview';

            setup_postdata( $post );

            do_action('wp-freeio-before-preview-service', $post);

            echo WP_Freeio_Template_Loader::get_template_part( 'service-submission/service-submit-preview', array(
                'post_id' => $this->service_id,
                'service_id'         => $this->service_id,
                'step'           => $this->get_step(),
                'form_obj'           => $this,
            ) );
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    }

    public function preview_process() {
        if ( ! $_POST ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( !isset( $_POST['security-service-submit-preview'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['security-service-submit-preview'], 'wp-freeio-service-submit-preview-nonce' )  ) {
            $this->errors[] = esc_html__('Your nonce did not verify.', 'wp-freeio');
            return;
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['continue-edit-service'] ) ) {
            $this->step --;
        } elseif ( isset( $_POST['continue-submit-service'] ) ) {
            $service = get_post( $this->service_id );

            if ( in_array( $service->post_status, array( 'preview', 'expired' ), true ) ) {
                // Reset expiry.
                delete_post_meta( $service->ID, WP_FREEIO_SERVICE_PREFIX.'expiry_date' );

                // Update service listing.
                $review_before = wp_freeio_get_option( 'submission_service_requires_approval' );
                $post_status = 'publish';
                if ( $review_before == 'on' ) {
                    $post_status = 'pending';
                }

                $freelancer_user_id = WP_Freeio_User::get_user_id();
                $update_service                  = array();
                $update_service['ID']            = $service->ID;
                $update_service['post_status']   = apply_filters( 'wp_freeio_submit_service_post_status', $post_status, $service );
                $update_service['post_date']     = current_time( 'mysql' );
                $update_service['post_date_gmt'] = current_time( 'mysql', 1 );
                $update_service['post_author']   = $freelancer_user_id;

                wp_update_post( $update_service );
            }

            $this->step ++;
        }
    }

    public function done_output() {
        $service = get_post( $this->service_id );
        
        echo WP_Freeio_Template_Loader::get_template_part( 'service-submission/service-submit-done', array(
            'post_id' => $this->service_id,
            'service'     => $service,
        ) );
    }

    public function done_handler() {
        do_action( 'wp_freeio_service_submit_done', $this->service_id );
        
        if ( ! empty( $_COOKIE['service_add_new_update'] ) ) {
            $service_add_new_update = $_COOKIE['service_add_new_update'];

            if ( wp_freeio_get_option('admin_notice_add_new_service') ) {
                $service = get_post($this->service_id);
                $email_from = get_option( 'admin_email', false );
                
                $headers = sprintf( "From: %s <%s>\r\n Content-type: text/html", get_bloginfo('name'), $email_from );
                $email_to = get_option( 'admin_email', false );
                $subject = WP_Freeio_Email::render_email_vars(array('service' => $service), 'admin_notice_add_new_service', 'subject');
                $content = WP_Freeio_Email::render_email_vars(array('service' => $service), 'admin_notice_add_new_service', 'content');
                
                WP_Freeio_Email::wp_mail( $email_to, $subject, $content, $headers );
            }
            
            setcookie( 'service_add_new_update', '', time() - HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
        }
    }
}

function wp_freeio_service_submit_form() {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['wp_freeio_service_submit_form'] ) ) {
        WP_Freeio_Service_Submit_Form::get_instance();
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'wp_freeio_service_submit_form' );

and Here's my approach :
<?php 
if (!defined("ABSPATH")) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/wp-freeio/includes/class-service-abstract-form.php';

require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/wp-freeio/includes/class-service-submit-form.php';

class Custom_WP_Freeio_Service_Submit_Form extends WP_Freeio_Service_Submit_Form {
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function get_instance() {
        if ( null === self::$instance ) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function get_freelancer_service_count($user_id) {
        // Implement your logic to count services for the given freelancer ID
        // Example logic (assuming 'service' is your post type):
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'service',
            'post_status'    => array( 'publish', 'pending', 'draft' ),
            'author'         => $user_id,
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // Get all posts
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        return $query->found_posts;
    }

    public function submit_process() {
        error_log('Custom Class Triggered');
        /************ GigTN Custom Code firas_footprint_gigs_limit */
        $max_gigs_verified = 1;
        $max_gigs_unverified = 1; 
        $user_id = WP_Freeio_User::get_user_id();
        $gigs_count = $this->get_freelancer_service_count($user_id);
        error_log('Gigs Count ' . $gigs_count);
        $freelancer_id = WP_Freeio_User::get_freelancer_by_user_id($user_id);
        $verified = get_post_meta($freelancer_id, "verified", true);

        if ( $verified && $gigs_count >= $max_gigs_verified ) {
            $this->errors[] = sprintf( __( 'You have reached the maximum limit of %d gigs.', 'wp-freeio' ), $max_gigs_verified );
            return;
        }
        if ( !$verified && $gigs_count >= $max_gigs_unverified ) {
            $this->errors[] = sprintf( __( 'You have reached the maximum limit of %d gig. Verify your account to increase the limit to 10.', 'wp-freeio' ), $max_gigs_unverified );
            return;
        }
        /* END CUSTOM */

        // Call the parent class's submit_process method
        parent::submit_process();
    }

    public function get_steps() {
        $steps = parent::get_steps();
        $steps['submit']['handler'] = array( $this, 'submit_process' );
        return $steps;
    }
}

function replace_wp_freeio_service_submit_form() {
    if (class_exists('WP_Freeio_Service_Submit_Form')) {
        // Ensure the original instance's process method is not hooked
        remove_action('wp', array(WP_Freeio_Service_Submit_Form::get_instance(), 'submit_process'));

        // Create an instance of your custom class
        $custom_form_instance = Custom_WP_Freeio_Service_Submit_Form::get_instance();

        // Add the custom class process action
        add_action('wp', array($custom_form_instance, 'submit_process'));
    }
}
add_action('init', 'replace_wp_freeio_service_submit_form');


But that didn't seem to work.
I do get the error_logs I added to the custom method, but while modifying the original file did the trick and shows the error before submitting ( since i set max_verified and max_unverified to 1 to test ), but with my approach it just goes through and posts the service.
What am I doing wrong here?
